# Custom alert and confirm box in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any `alert` and `confirm` dialog available in `jquery` with custom title and custom content in it. I have searched many sites but cannot find appropriate. Any site link or any content are appreciable.

Comment: You need to deal with jquery dialog

Comment: Apart from browser specific solutions that *may* exist, you'll not be able to manually style the `alert` and `confirm` boxes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I made custom messagebox using `jquery UI` component. Here is demo http://jsfiddle.net/eraj2587/Pm5Fr/14/

You have to pass just the parameters like caption name, message, button's text. You can specify trigger function on any button click. This will helpful for you.

Comment: But it doesn't block the code. As statement after alert get execute only when 'Ok' press.

Comment: I see blank instead of images http://code--projects.com/custom-dialog/ . Can you please explain why?

Comment: @partho : if you see console there are 10 errors in your page that image files are not downloaded in browser. Make sure that you have these files in folder. examples are

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://code--projects.com/custom-dialog/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://code--projects.com/custom-dialog/images/ui-bg_highlight-hard_100_f9f9f9_1x100.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 11):

Try using [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) its just simply the best .
You will get a lot of customization and flexibility.

#### Confirm Example

```
sweetAlert(
  {
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
    type: "warning",   
    showCancelButton: true,   
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!"
  }, 
  deleteIt()
);
```

[image: Sample Alert]

Comment: Its pretty good but it also affects my div! when it pops up, there's a change in my div position.

Answer (score 3):

Check the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CdwB9/3/ and click on delete

```
function yesnodialog(button1, button2, element){
  var btns = {};
  btns[button1] = function(){ 
      element.parents('li').hide();
      $(this).dialog("close");
  };
  btns[button2] = function(){ 
      // Do nothing
      $(this).dialog("close");
  };
  $("<div></div>").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    title: 'Condition',
    modal:true,
    buttons:btns
  });
}
$('.delete').click(function(){
    yesnodialog('Yes', 'No', $(this));
})
```

This should help you

Answer (score 2):

You can use the dialog widget of JQuery UI

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery UI** has it's own elements, but jQuery alone hasn't.

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Working example:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```