# how to add a logo or picture to the alert box using jquery and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popupwindow

i want to add an icon in the alert box beside the text using jquery and html

the alert box work fine but when i tried to add an icon i did not know how to add it can anyone help me ???

in this code how to add a picture or an icon

using jquery UI

## index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal message</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />!-->

<script>
$(function() {
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
modal: true,
buttons: {
Ok: function() {
$( this ).dialog( "close" );
}
}
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog-message" title="Download complete">
<p>
<!--<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 50px 0;"></span>!-->
<span img src = "img1.jpg" style ="float: left; margin:0 7px 50px 0; width:50px; height:50px;"></span>
Your files have downloaded successfully into the My Downloads folder.
</p>
<p>
Currently using <b>36% of your storage space</b>.
</p>
</div>
<p>Sed vel diam id libero <a href="http://example.com">rutrum convallis</a>. Donec aliquet leo vel magna. Phasellus rhoncus faucibus ante. Etiam bibendum, enim faucibus aliquet rhoncus, arcu felis ultricies neque, sit amet auctor elit eros a lectus.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't...you have to make a custom modal window...

Comment: @ aldanux what did you mean and where can i find a tutorial to create a custom modal window

Comment: Bootstrap's Modal box is very customizable and easy to use, check it out and see if it's an option: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

Comment: Example this one: [Modal Reveal](http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

alert() won't render images :-(

If you could add more detail about what you're trying to accomplish with the alert, we can come up with a suitable alternative.

Since you're already using jQuery, this may interest you: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: sir i want to add a picture like a logo for some company within the alert box or the popup window using jquery  can you give me some valuable tutorials to follow it??

Comment: There are entire books written about jQuery UI. Try Amazon.com.

Comment: @LebDev: Sure, see the view-source link on http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ for a code example. You can use your typical <img src=""> within the <div id="dialog">.

And see the variations under the "Examples" section on the right side of that page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you need to see this tutorial:
http://slayeroffice.com/code/custom_alert/

[Dialog boxes](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) can be helpful as well:
[Custom alert and confirm box in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648522/custom-alert-and-confirm-box-in-jquery)

Comment: Dialog boxes using jQuery ui is really great!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with bootstrap,

download bootstrap,

http://getbootstrap.com/

add the three files to your root site folder.

Get bootbox.js from this guys blog, He actually gives you a tutorial on this as well. 
The file you download will have a working example of a alert box that has been styled.

http://creativitytuts.org/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial-15-bootbox-js-alert-dialogs/

then to see an actual alertbox done with bootstrap jquery you can go to this page and the very last example is exactly what your asking for...

http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html

This will get you your image. The only problem I am having is resizing the images. But this is probably an error on my part.

Hope this helped!

Here is a working example of the code,

HTML:

```
<div class="btn1">
<button>click me</button>
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
```

JS:

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.btn1').on('click', function(){
    var some_html = '<img class="alert" src="img/pic1.jpg" width="30px" /><br />';
    some_html += '<h2>You can use custom HTML too!</h2><br />';
    some_html += '<h4>Just be sure to mind your quote marks</h4>';
    bootbox.alert(some_html);               
                    });    
            });         
     </script>
```