# HTTP error browser popup

Tags: javascript, http, browser, server

On my site I have a table that queries the DB every 30 seconds to update its content. If I stop the web server while a page is open in the browser, when requests are made to the DB they return a server error displayed in a browser pop-up window that doesn't allow the user to click anything other than "OK". Are these alert pop-ups customizable or is it just default browser specific behavior. I would like to make the alerts less intrusive and more informative, so that if something does happen to my production server a message can be sent to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the browser pop-ups using the alert() function (which I assume you are using) cannot be changed as they are a system object, not subject to css. If you would like to make a custom pop up you can use the JqueryUI to create one or create a custom popup.

See this question for how to create a custom alert/pop-up using JQuery UI:  [Custom alert and confirm box in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648522/custom-alert-and-confirm-box-in-jquery)