# How can I have jQuery dialog behave like Javascript alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The issue of substituting one’s own ‘alert’ by contriving a jQuery dialog has been debated previously, for instance here :

[Custom alert and confirm box in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648522/custom-alert-and-confirm-box-in-jquery)

In that thread Hemant Malpote objected rightly: « But it [the proposed jQuery dialog-based solution] doesn't block the code. [where]As statement[s] after [a Javascript] alert get execute[d] only when 'Ok' [is] press[ed] ». (Letters or words inside brackets were added by me for the sake of clarity.)
I should add that this can wholly change the behaviour of a chunk of code.

How can I design a jQuery dialog so that it behaves the way the Javascript alert does, i.e. stops executing until a dismissal button gets pressed ?

Comment: think differently and wrap whatever you need to execute in a promise callback and resolve that promise with dialog button

Comment: You can use sweet alert at here https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/

Comment: Thanks to charlietfl and Fil. I have heard about SweetAlert and am going to give it a go.

Comment: @Fil — I have just tested SweetAlert, not thourougly, I confess. Implementing their test code junk —swal({ title: "Error!", text: "Here's my error message!", type: "error", confirmButtonText: "Cool" });— in my own code shows that their 'alert' behaves exactly as a jQuery dialog. Am I missing something? Any clue?

Comment: You need to load jquery library, css, and sweetalert.js to make it work

Comment: @Fil — I tried this (I am not really a newbie) but, as stated previously, SweetAlerts just behave the way regular jQuery dialogs do. See my comment hereafter to charlietfl.

Comment: @charlietfl — I think that is the right thing to do —and I did so—, at least as far as my specific problem needed to be solved: the deferring device works smoothly, is easy to implement and apparently sports many extended possibilities. Cheers !

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

The closest you can come is to cancel whatever triggered it entirely, and then start something new (but similar to what you canceled) when the button is clicked.

Comment: Please see my reply to charlietfl. Though you are quite right, the deferring device is a good workaround.

Comment: @BriceCoustillas — That's more or less what this answer is suggesting.